Symbol lookup error for List::Util Perl module after RHEL7 to RHEL8 upgrade
we have recently upgraded our system from RHEL7 to RHEL8 , and when executing below command we are getting error
RHEL7.9  = Perl 5.16.3
RHEL8.10 = Perl 5.26.3
Command 1:

perl -MList::Util -e 'print "$List::Util::VERSION\n";'

Command 2:

cpan -r List::Util

Command 3:

cpan List::Util

Error:

perl: symbol lookup error:
/usr/local/lib64/perl5/auto/List/Util/Util.so: undefined symbol:
Perl_xs_apiversion_bootcheck

How we can resolve this, since reinstalling module from cpan is not working
Please guide.
Regards,
Samurai

On a RHEL 8.9 system, after a fresh install of dnf install perl:
# perl -MList::Util -e 'print "$List::Util::VERSION\n";'
1.49

RHEL 8 includes version 1.49 of List::Util, packaged as perl-Scalar-List-Utils. It is one of standard dependencies of RHEL 8's perl metapackage, so it is most likely already installed on your system. It lives at /usr/lib64/perl5/vendor_perl/List/Util.pm.
But your system has another version of List::Util installed locally, that was apparently originally built for RHEL 7. After all Perl RPM packages have been upgraded from RHEL 7.x to RHEL 8.x, it is now out of date and incompatible with the current Perl version. Since the locally-installed versions have a higher priority than the packaged ones, the old local version now causes a conflict with the RPM-packaged Perl version.
You probably should probably do mv /usr/local/lib64/perl5 /usr/local/lib64/perl5.obsolete or something similar to remove the conflict, and then go through all the module directories under /usr/local/lib64/perl5.obsolete/auto/, identifying each previously locally-built Perl module, and checking:

do you still need that module, or has the requirement for it become obsolete in the RHEL major version upgrade?
if you still need it, is there an acceptable version available as a RedHat RPM? If so, you should generally prefer installing it, as you will then get updates automatically if there is an issue with that version.
if you still need a version newer than is packaged for RHEL 8, reinstall it from CPAN it now. As the conflicting old locally-built Perl modules have now been deactivated by moving their directory hierarchy out of its expected location, reinstalling from CPAN should now work better.


Thank you telcoM, we have analysed based on your suggestions,  we reinstalled module
